# Purge elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to install elasticsearch version 5.4, but when I am trying to remove elasticsearch I am getting below error:
sudo apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch
[sudo] password for ank:
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Could someone help in solving the error and also in installation of elasticsearch 5.4

Comment: 5.X is very very much EOL and no longer supported. why do you want to use it?

Comment: I have to use it for some projects where type should work.